# Can't Return Any Data With New Version of JQuery Datatable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I'm developing an ASP.Net MVC 5 web application using JQuery Datatables version 1.10.4. I wish to populate the Datatable using an Ajax call to my Controller which will return Json data.

In previous applications I have used JQuery Datatable versions 1.9 or less. Now that I've upgraded my version and found that my usual trustworthy code no longer works. Could someone please help me out here?

**My Razor View**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#dataTables-example').dataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,

        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Shift/GetShifts",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
        { "data": "shiftDateID" },
        { "data": "shiftTitle" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "description" },
        { "data": "shiftStartDate" },
        { "data": "shiftEndDate" }
    ]
    });

});
```

```
<table id="dataTables-example" class="display compact" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ref</th>
            <th>Shift</th>
            <th>Trust</th>
            <th>Hospital</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**My Controller**

```
public JsonResult GetShifts(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{
            IEnumerable<ShiftDate> allShifts;

            allShifts = _shiftDateService.GetAllShiftDatesToBeFilled();

            IEnumerable<ShiftDate> filteredShifts;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
            {
                filteredShifts = _shiftDateService.GetAllShiftDatesToBeFilled()
                            .Where(s => s.Shift.shiftTitle.ToUpper().Contains(param.sSearch.ToUpper())).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                filteredShifts = allShifts;
            }

            var displayedShifts = filteredShifts;
            displayedShifts = displayedShifts
                        .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
                        .Take(param.iDisplayLength);

            var aaData = displayedShifts.Select(s => new string[] { Convert.ToString(s.shiftDateID), s.Shift.shiftTitle, s.Shift.Organisation.description, s.Shift.Locations.FirstOrDefault().ListItem.description, s.shiftStartDate.ToShortDateString(), s.shiftEndDate.ToShortDateString()}).ToArray();

            return Json(new
            {
                sEcho = param.sEcho,
                aaData = aaData,
                iTotalRecords = allShifts.Count(),
                iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredShifts.Count()
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }  

}

public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
{
    public string sEcho { get; set; }
    public string sSearch { get; set; }
    public int iDisplayLength { get; set; }
    public int iDisplayStart { get; set; }
}
```

The above code now doesn't work, i.e., return any data. Could anyone please advise me on what changes need made to get my code working with the newer version of JQuery Datatables?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The parameters sent to the server and the expected parameters returned have changed between 1.9 and 1.10. An example below:

```
return Json(new
{
    error = param.sEcho,
    data = aaData,
    recordsTotal = allShifts.Count(),
    recordsFiltered = filteredShifts.Count()
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

To see the full list of changes for your use case go [here](http://www.datatables.net/manual/server-side).